# Ckeditor на сайте показывает html-код вместо текста

Tags: php, html, laravel, веб-программирование, ckeditor

Столкнулся с проблемой, что этот редактор выводит html-код вместо текста.

```
@foreach ($about_s1 as $item)


      <a href="{{ url('/aboutus/'.$item->id) }}">
                            {{ $item->ckeditor  }}
                            <h5>{{ $item->ckeditor1}}</h5>
                        </a>


                    @endforeach
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: всё правильно. для этого используйте `{!! $item->ckeditor1 !!}`

Comment: бред. Я через ckeditor1 передаю текст.

Comment: А если я подставлю это, то мне выведет { !! $item->ckeditor !! }

Comment: Выводить сырой HTML в цикле – явно к беде.Редактор выплевывает контент, переведенный в HTML-сущности.

Comment: Оно даже в бд заносит так, думаю дело не в этом

Comment: А нет, Дмитрий, извиняюсь, вы были правы, спасибо!

Comment: @Resawa рад что помог! =)